# JPA - Java não insere dados no banco

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Bean

```
 @Named("proprietarioMB")
     public class ProprietarioBean  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private ProprietarioService proprietarioService;

    @Inject
    private Proprietario proprietario = null;

    private String dataTemp;

    public Proprietario getProprietario() {
        return proprietario;
    }

    public void setProprietario(Proprietario proprietario) {
        this.proprietario = proprietario;
    }



    public String getDataTemp() {
        return dataTemp;
    }

    public void setDataTemp(String dataTemp) {
        this.dataTemp = dataTemp;
    }



    private void stringToDate(){
        SimpleDateFormat tmp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        try {
            Date date = tmp.parse(getDataTemp());
            proprietario.setDataNascimento(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void InsereProprietario(){
        //stringToDate();


                proprietarioService.criar(proprietario);


    }


}
```

Model

```
    @Entity
public class Proprietario implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name ="cpfProprietario")
    private int cpf;

    @Column(name ="nome" ,length=100)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name ="endereco" ,length=100)
    private String endereco;

    @Column(name ="bairro" , length=100)
    private String bairro;

    @Column(name ="cidade" ,length=100)
    private String cidade;

    @Column(name ="uf" ,length=2)
    private String uf;


    @Column(name ="sexo" ,length=1)
    private String sexo;

    @Column(name ="dtNascimento")
    private Date dataNascimento;

    public int getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(int cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getUf() {
        return uf;
    }

    public void setUf(String uf) {
        this.uf = uf;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public Date getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }

    public void setDataNascimento(Date dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }


}
```

Service

```
public class ProprietarioService implements Serializable {
     @Inject
     private ProprietarioRepository proprietarioRepository;

     //CRIAR

     public void criar(Proprietario proprietario){

         proprietarioRepository.criar(proprietario);


     }

     //EDITAR

     //DELETAR

     //BUSCAR

}
```

Repository

```
    public class ProprietarioRepository implements Serializable {

    @Inject 
    private EntityManager manager;


    public void criar(Proprietario proprietario) {
        try{

            this.manager.persist(proprietario);

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }


    }

}
```

no meu console não imprime nada, algum norte?

Answer (score 0):

Como está a sua configuração com o banco de dados?

Aparentemente está faltando a transação aí.

Antes do persist faça:

```
manager.getTransaction().begin();
```

E depois do persist:

```
manager.getTransaction().commit();
```

O ideal é que a transação fique em um escopo bem maior que só o salvar, como por exemplo durante a requisição toda

Comment: quando uso manager.getTransaction().begin(); ele fala que não é para usar "A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()"

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta substituir o `@Inject`do seu `EntityManager` por `@PersistenceContext`. Dependendo como estiver configurado o seu `persist.xml` (ou outro nome para o arquivo de configuração da implementação do JPA) é necessário abrir e fechar a transação conforme citado acima.